# R check if datasets contain "USA" or "TheUnitedStatesOfAmerica"

Tags: r, merge

I have 2 Sets of data:

```
set1:
cntry,inhabitants
Germany,82
France, 66
USA, 328
```

```
set2:
Country,Life_expectation
Spanin,83.33
France,82.5
UnitedStatesOfAmerica, 78.5
```

```
merged_set <- merge(subset1,subset2,by.x = "cntry","Country")
```

I want USA and UnitedStatesOfAmerica to be recognized as the same.

How can I do that?

expected Out put:

```
merged_set:
France,66,82.5
USA,328,78.5
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just rename `UnitedStatesOfAmerica` to `USA`:

```
subset1$Country <- ifelse(subset1$Country == "UnitedStatesOfAmerica",
                         "USA", subset1$Country)
subset2$Country <- ifelse(subset2$Country == "UnitedStatesOfAmerica",
                         "USA", subset2$Country)
merged_set <- merge(subset1, subset2, by.x="cntry", by.y="Country")
```

Note that I am defensively renaming in both source data frames although your sample data might imply that only the second one needs to be renamed.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just to make sure: ```merged_set <- merge(subset1, subset2, by.x = "cntry", "Country")``` is the same as: ```merged_set <- merge(subset1, subset2, by.x = "cntry", by.y = "Country"); ``` right?

Comment: @lightyears99 Yes, but you should probably _always_ use your second version, to avoid any amiguity.  I have also updated my answer.

Comment: One more question here: Does ifelse in this case scan the whole dataset for occurences of UnitedStatesOfAmerica? So it implys a loop?

Comment: The `ifelse` function is vectorized in R.  So, we don't see an explicit loop, but yes, internally, there is some kind of looping over the vector to search for matches.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` approach, you could solve your problem as follows:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(set2)[Country == "UnitedStatesOfAmerica", Country := "USA"]

set2[set1, on=c(Country = 'cntry'), nomatch=NULL]

#    Country Life_expectation inhabitants
# 1:  France             82.5          66
# 2:     USA             78.5         328
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the country column equal in both the dataframes so either change `'UnitedStatesOfAmerica'` to `'USA'` or vice-versa. We can use `case_when` to perform this replacement so if you have any other country with different names you can add them in this list as well before performing the join.

```
library(dplyr)

set2 %>%
  mutate(Country = case_when(Country == 'UnitedStatesOfAmerica'~'USA', 
                             TRUE ~ Country)) %>%
  inner_join(set1, by = c('Country' = 'cntry'))

#  Country Life_expectation inhabitants
#1  France             82.5          66
#2     USA             78.5         328
```